# Update color of shape depending on calculated cells value

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I am trying to show a status of a particular percentage variable with a colored shape where the higher it is the worse it is.  I tried using Worksheet_Change but that wasn't working because this is a calculate cell and It wont be changed directly by the user.  What is wrong with my Worksheet_Calculate syntax?

I've tried with just normal numbers (not percentages) and it still doesn't work.

This is the code on the sheet

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Dim target As Range
 Set target = Range("A1")
 If Not Intersect(target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
 If IsNumeric(target.Value) Then
     If target.Value < 0.1 Then
         ActiveSheet.Shapes("Oval 1").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbGreen
     ElseIf target.Value >= 0.1 And target.Value < 0.25 Then
         ActiveSheet.Shapes("Oval 1").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbBlue
          ElseIf target.Value >= 0.25 And target.Value < 0.5 Then
         ActiveSheet.Shapes("Oval 1").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbBlue
     Else
         ActiveSheet.Shapes("Oval 1").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbRed
     End If
 End If
 End If
 
End Sub
```

Thank you,
Lewp

Comment: First of all, everything involved to `Target` can be removed. Just check `Range("A1").Value`.

Comment: @bigBen So something like this directly after worksheet_calculate? `If Not Range("A1").Value Is Nothing Then
 If IsNumeric(Range("A1").Value) Then
     If Range("A1").Value < 0.1 Then`   then so and and so forth

Comment: Get rid of the `If Not Range("A1").Value Is Nothing Then`, but yes.

Comment: That works, Thanks a ton.  Ill paste my finished code as an answer for future searchers

Answer (score 2):

Code worked as follows,

```
 If IsNumeric(Range("A1").Value) Then
     If Range("A1").Value < 0.1 Then
         ActiveSheet.Shapes("Oval 1").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbGreen
     ElseIf Range("A1").Value >= 0.1 And Range("A1").Value < 0.25 Then
         ActiveSheet.Shapes("Oval 1").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbBlue
          ElseIf Range("A1").Value >= 0.25 And Range("A1").Value < 0.5 Then
         ActiveSheet.Shapes("Oval 1").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbYellow
     Else
         ActiveSheet.Shapes("Oval 1").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbRed
     End If
 End If
 
End Sub
```

Thanks to @BigBen